# Are there $4$ sets such that the sum of the two numbers are equal?

Tags: combinatorics

For each set of $117$ different $3-$ digit natural numbers,can we choose $4$ disjoint sets with $2$ elements $A,B,C,D$ with the identity:the sums of the two numbers of each set are equal?

How can I check this??

I got stuck right now...

Could you give me a hint??

Comment: there are $117 \choose 2$ subsets of order 2, and those sums range from 200 to 2000

Comment: But I want the sum of the two numbers of each set to be equal. Is it possible to find such 4 subjects?

Comment: yes, there are 6786 different sums being mapped to about 1800 different values.  you can use the pigeonhole principle to conclude 4 such sums will map to the same value.  I'm not sure why 117 is thrown in there, it seems you could do it with fewer

Answer (score 0):

From the requirement that each of the set $A,B,C,D$ should have two elements, I presume that sum of two elements of a set means 'sum of two distinct elements of a set'. Otherwise, the solution below can be modified accordingly.

The least possible sum is 100+101=201 and maximum possible sum is 998+999=1997. But, not every sum is expressible as sum of four distinct unordered pairs. For example, 205=100+105=101+104=102+103 -- only three pairs. The least sum that is expressible as sum of four distinct unordered pairs is 207(=103+104) and the maximum is 1991(=995+996). Hence the number of sums that are expressible as sum of at least four distinct unordered pairs is 1991-206=1785.

Let $S$ be the multiset of all possible sums of 117 distinct three digit numbers. The following sums can occur with their maximum multiplicities.

> sum -- multiplicity
>
> - 201 -- 1
> - 202 -- 1
> - 203 -- 2
> - 204 -- 2
> - 205 -- 3
> - 206 -- 3
> - 207 -- 4 or 4+
> - ...
> - 1991 -- 4 or 4+
> - 1992 -- 3
> - 1993 -- 3
> - 1994 -- 2
> - 1995 -- 2
> - 1996 -- 1
> - 1997 -- 1

Hence, there are $\binom{117}{2}-24=6774$ sums expressible as sum of at least four distinct unordered pairs. We have $\frac{6774}{1785}=3.79$ (up to two digits). By pigeon hole principle, there must be four distinct unordered pairs with the required property. Among the four distinct ordered pairs, we cannot have unordered pairs of form $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ where $c\ne b$ as $a+b\ne a+c$. Hence for any two unordered pairs (four distinct ordered pairs), $(m,n)$ and $p,q$, we have $m\ne p,m\ne q,n\ne p,n\ne q$. Hence, we have four sets of size 2, each containing the elements of four unordered pairs respectively.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but i was curious: why do you subtract 24 from all possible pairs of 117 numbers? They also should not represent sums, but only pairs of numbers.